# It compiles but crashes with exc_bad_access

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, file-io

The program compiles but crashes at

`fscanf ( fileHandle, "%d", &numberPeople );`

I think it has to do with memory allocation OR the file pointer goes out of scope and then is pointing at the wrong location.

These are just guesses though based off compiler error:

`Thread 1: exc_bad_access(code=1, address=0x68)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

//salesman struct
struct Salesman
{
    char firstname[64];
    char lastname[64];
    char middleinitial[1];
    int averagecents;
    int totalcents;
};

void calculateAveragesTotals(FILE*, int, int, int, int);
void tableWriter(int, int, int, int);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    //setup variables
    const char* inputFilename = "TheSales.txt";
    int numberPeople = 0, weeksToHandlePerPerson = 0;
    int workweeklength = 5;
    int totalcents = 0;

    //open file
    FILE* fileHandle = fopen ( inputFilename, "r" );
    fscanf ( fileHandle, "%d", &numberPeople );
    fscanf ( fileHandle, "%d", &weeksToHandlePerPerson );

   calculateAveragesTotals(fileHandle, numberPeople, weeksToHandlePerPerson, workweeklength, totalcents);

    int averagecents = totalcents / ( numberPeople * weeksToHandlePerPerson );

    std::cout << "total for all: " << totalcents / 100 << "." << totalcents % 100 << " and     average for all $" <<
    averagecents / 100 << "." << averagecents % 100 << std::endl;

}


 void calculateAveragesTotals(FILE* fileHandle, int numberPeople, int weeksToHandle, int workweeklength, int totalcents) {
    //do calculations
    for ( int i = 0; i < numberPeople; ++i )
    {
        Salesman nextsalesman;
        fscanf ( fileHandle, "%s", nextsalesman.firstname );
        fscanf ( fileHandle, "%s", nextsalesman.middleinitial );
        fscanf ( fileHandle, "%s", nextsalesman.lastname );

        float t1, t2, t3, t4, t5;
        fscanf ( fileHandle, "%f %f %f %f %f", &t1, &t2, &t3, &t4, &t5 );

        nextsalesman.totalcents = 100 * ( t1 + t2 + t3 + t4 + t5 );
        nextsalesman.averagecents = nextsalesman.totalcents / workweeklength;
        totalcents += nextsalesman.totalcents;

        //print calculations calculateNumbers()
        std::cout << "salesman " << i << " total: $" << nextsalesman.totalcents / 100 << "." <<     nextsalesman.totalcents % 100
        << " and average $" << nextsalesman.averagecents / 100 << "." << nextsalesman.averagecents % 100 << std::endl;

    }
 }
```

Comment: `FILE* fileHandle = fopen ( inputFilename, "r" );` Check value of `fileHandle`

Comment: This is no C code. Do not attach C tag for C++ code. These are different languages.

Comment: "Thread 1: exc_bad_access(code=1, address=0x68)". Is not a compiler error. Looks more like a runtime-error. Limit the strings you read with fscanf! You have your code wide open for buffer overflow, aka _undefined bahaviour_.

Comment: @Olaf I guess I am confused. fscanf is c code, the struct is c code, stdio.h is a c library. cout is c++. Technically it is more c then c++. If I include just one c++ thing should I drop the c tag? I'm not trying to argue I'm legitimately confused.    I'll look into the buffer overflows.

Comment: @asd: You're indeed mixing C and C++ code. The problem apparently is in the C part, and most likely would be fixed if you'd use C++ consistently. `file >> numberOfPeople` wouldn't crash.

Comment: Once you use C++ code, you obviously are not C compatible anymore. OTOH, you can compile with C++ compiler, so that is valid C++ code. Problem are the subtle differences between both languages, which make such transfers potentially problematic.

Comment: You should check the results of system functions. If fopen fails, for example, all following file-functions present UB, as they get a _null pointer_.